# How can I change the admin search posts fields?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, admin, search

I have a custom post type that includes many custom fields.
I would like to add them as a search target to admin search.

Currently the admin search searches only the content and the title, I would like it to search these custom fields as well.

Is there a way to do that ?

Comment: I have been looking for this same thing for ages. I needed to search properties by ref number in the wordpress admin.
Finally I found this brilliant plug-in: [http://wordpress.org/plugins/search-everything/](http://wordpress.org/plugins/search-everything/)
Check it out; it can search any field and custom field!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It *is* possible, but you'll have to play a little bit with the actual query. As always, the furious `posts_clauses` filter comes to action:

```
function wpse_alter_posts_search( $pieces )
{
    global $wpdb;

    // Make the input save
    $search_string = like_escape( $_GET['s'] );

    // Your new WHERE clause
    $where  = $wpdb->prepare(
        "$wpdb->postmeta.%s LIKE %s",
        'YOUR_COLUMN', // Should match your col name 1)
        "%{$search_string}%"
    );

    // Not sure if this exactly the same on your install 2)
    $pieces['where'] = str_replace( 'AND (((', "AND ((({$where} ", $pieces['where'] );

    return $pieces;
}
add_filter( 'posts_clauses', 'wpse_alter_posts_search' );
```

---

**NOTES**

1. Could be that you need to unserialize some parts to be search able.
2. You better simply dump the `$pieces` to take a look into them, before altering the query (right after the `$search_string` was received).

Comment: Or `posts_where` :D

Comment: @StephenHarris I personally prefer the »alltogether« `posts_clauses` filter. No need to remember those (imho unnecessary) other filters...

Comment: I guess like_escape should be a function that escapes the search string to like format. can you please add it ? I'me having problems with this...

Comment: Added `like_escape()`ed to the `prepare()`. And no: It doesn't reformat the input search string. It makes it just save for queries, like other `esc_*` functions do for other tasks.

Answer (score 3):

kaiser's answer got me on the right track but I had to join the `postmeta` table and add a group by as well.

Now `like_escape` is `$wpdb->esc_like`. Replace `[your_post_type]` with your post type and `[your_postmeta_key]` with your meta key:

```
//join postmeta for search
add_filter( 'posts_join' , function($join){
    global $wpdb;
    if(is_search() && is_admin() && $_GET['post_type'] == '[your_post_type]')
    {
     $join .= " LEFT JOIN $wpdb->postmeta ON $wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->postmeta.post_id ";
    }
     return $join;
});

//search [your_postmeta_key] for search string
add_filter( 'posts_where', function( $where )
{
    global $wpdb;
    if(is_search() && is_admin() && $_GET['post_type'] == '[your_post_type]')
    {
        $searchstring = '%' . $wpdb->esc_like( $_GET['s'] ) . '%';
        //search [your_postmeta_key] as well
        $where .= $wpdb->prepare(" OR ($wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = '[your_postmeta_key]' AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value LIKE %s) ", $searchstring);   
    }
    return $where;
});

//group by post ID
add_filter( 'posts_groupby', function ($groupby, $query) {

    global $wpdb;
    if(is_search() && is_admin() && $_GET['post_type'] == '[your_post_type]')
    {
        $groupby = "{$wpdb->posts}.ID";
    }
    return $groupby;

}, 10, 2 );
```